# Cannot boot recorvery

Tags: macos, mac-mini, recovery

I am trying to re-install our Mac Mini. Looking around Apple's website, it seems the `Recovery Disk Assistant` is the way to do it.

I have followed the instructions for the [`OSX Recovery Disk Assistant 1.0`](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433).

When I boot, no matter what key combination I try, the boot selection screen does not appear. I have tried holing down the `Alt`, `Ctrl`, `C` and `Windows+R` keys.

I installed the assistant on an external hard drive and am using a Windows keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Windows keyboard, the Windows key is usually synonymous with option. Hold just the Windows key as the system boots and you'll get the... Options (get it?).

Failing that, if you have an internet connection, try Windows+r. If you don't have a recovery partition it should go to internet recovery and download what it needs from Apple.